# Why can't a string (from ARGV) be modified with shovel << (frozen string) in one case but it does can in another case?

Tags: ruby, string

I have two little ruby programs written in ruby 2.3.7
Im trying to extend strings that are passed from ARGV[].

This case works and extends the string removing last char and adding -ismo.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

if ARGV.length > 0                                      
    ARGV.each {|param| unless param.match(/ismo\z/); puts param.chop << "ismo" end} 
else
    puts "none"
end
```

but this other case doesnt work and says 'agranda' cant modify frozen String

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def reduce(string)
    puts string.slice(0,8)
end
def agranda(string)
    while string.length < 8
        string << 'z'           
    end
    puts string
end
if ARGV.length >= 1
    ARGV.each {|a| if a.length < 8; agranda(a) elsif a.length > 8; reduce(a) else puts a end}
else
    puts "none"
end
```

I cant figure it out why does it work in one case and doesnt in the other, both cases takes the string from the program arguments.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*ARGV* is a special Array, not a String. When working with frozen strings, you can append or modify an Array element even if you can't change the underlying String objects it contains. Forget *ARGV* for a moment, and consider this example of an unfrozen Array containing frozen strings:

```rb
a = ['foo', 'bar'].map &:freeze
a.first.frozen?
#=> true

a[0] = 'baz'; a
#=> ["baz", "bar"]

a.map &:frozen?
#=> [false, true]
```

Now consider a frozen Array with unfrozen String elements:

```rb
a = ['foo', 'bar'].freeze
a.frozen?
#=> true

# Array is frozen, and yet...
a[0] << 'bar'; a
#=> ["foobar", "bar"]
```

In the first case, you can modify the Array but you can't mutate String elements in place; you have to replace them. In the second case, you can't add or remove elements of your Array, but you can mutate String objects stored within the Array.

From a practical perspective, you need to figure out what object is actually frozen. While you can't unfreeze a String or other object, you can certainly modify things it points to (e.g. an unfrozen String object within a frozen Array), or duplicate an unfrozen version of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Your first one (which works) says this:

```
param.chop << "ismo"
```

Your second one (which doesn't work) says this:

```
string << 'z'
```

The first calls [`String#chop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chop) which gives you a copy of `param` with the last character removed and then shovels `'ismo'` onto the end of that copy. The implicit copying in the `String#chop` call gives you an unfrozen string.

The second tries to shovel right into `string` without any copying. Your `agranda` method needs to copy the string and then modify that copy. The [unary `+` operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2B-40) for strings is specifically meant for this:

```
def agranda(string)
  string = +string
  # ...
```